# Why is there no network connectivity in Ubuntu using WSL 2 behind VPN?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1909

Premise: I'm trying to run Ubuntu as a Windows 10 app using WSL.

TL;DR problem: When Ubuntu uses WSL 2, network connectivity "disappears" when using company VPN.

Trying to get Ubuntu 18.04 (downloaded from the Microsoft Store) running on a Windows 10 work laptop (IT doesn't support Linux - I'm on my own) using `WSL 2`. When the corporate VPN is turned **off**, I seem to have network connectivity; when I'm connected to the VPN, suddenly I can't connect (`ping`, etc.) to anything.

There's probably a cascade of problems to deal with, so I'll try to limit the scope of this question: **why does Ubuntu report a `wifi0` NIC when it's using `WSL 1` but not when using `WSL 2`** (and does that matter)**?**

**Why can't I connect to anywhere only when using `WSL 2` and VPN is enabled?** Is the fix just a matter of adding the right `nameserver` to `/etc/resolv.conf`? If so, what's a valid value? I've already tried `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

---

**Ubuntu 18.04 `WSL 1`:**

```
$ ifconfig wifi0
wifi0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.96  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=64<RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.91.163  netmask 255.255.0.0
```

```
$ ping www.google.com # No VPN
PING forcesafesearch.google.com (216.239.38.120) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from any-in-2678.1e100.net (216.239.38.120): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=19.8 ms
64 bytes from any-in-2678.1e100.net (216.239.38.120): icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=22.0 ms
```

```
$ ping www.google.com # VPN active
PING forcesafesearch.google.com (216.239.38.120) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from any-in-2678.1e100.net (216.239.38.120): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=19.8 ms
64 bytes from any-in-2678.1e100.net (216.239.38.120): icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=22.0 ms
```

---

**Ubuntu 18.04 `WSL 2`:**

```
$ ifconfig wifi0
wifi0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.34.56  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 192.168.34.63
```

```
$ ping www.google.com # No VPN
PING www.google.com (142.250.68.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lax31s12-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.68.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=27.7 ms
64 bytes from lax31s12-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.68.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=19.6 ms
```

```
$ ping www.google.com # VPN active -- Both the generated and hand-edited /etc/resolv.conf failed
^C
```

---

**Update:**
I tried @StuartBrock's promising answer, but unfortunately it didn't work.

In Windows, `ipconfig /all` yielded the following, that I think are the DNS values for the VPN adapter:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
...
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
...
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
```

The following lines already exist in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

...and I've verified that as a result, edited content of `/etc/resolve.conf` persists across "reboots" (stop/restart of the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Windows app).

I'm not sure what the `fec` prefix and `%1` suffix are, but the values otherwise look like a IPV6 address. So I went ahead and updated my `/etc/resolve.conf` accordingly:

```
user@LOC-USER-LT:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.100.98.237
nameserver 10.100.98.21
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
```

...followed by the same test, i.e. `ping www.google.com`, and the behavior is unchanged from that originally-described.

The problem is still unchanged after a stop/restart of the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Windows app.

The problem is also unchanged if I update the `/etc/resolve.conf` content to remove the `fec` prefix and `%1` suffix, both before and after restarting the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Windows app:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.100.98.237
nameserver 10.100.98.21
nameserver 0:0:0:ffff::1
nameserver 0:0:0:ffff::2
nameserver 0:0:0:ffff::3
```

I'm not sure how intelligent `vim` is about the content of `/etc/resolve.conf`, but I found it interesting that it chose to red-highlight these new IPV6 values, as though it thought they were invalid:
[image: vim no like] [image]

---

**Update 2:**
I wondered whether the order of `/etc/resolve.conf` content mattered, so I tried placing the new IPV6 values at the top of the file. Interestingly, this *did* change behavior: instead of hanging for several seconds then failing with stderr `ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`, instead it *immediately* returns with the same stderr message.

Comment: What are your other network interfaces?  With Cisco AnyConnect the VPN has it's own network adaptor is this the same for you?  Also what are the contents of `resolv.conf` and your adaptor DNS settings on Windows?

Comment: What happens if you try to ping the IP address directly instead of using a FQDN? I can't even ping valid IP addresses on my network with VPN enabled...

Comment: @MikeLowery - same with me: unable to ping valid IP addresses on my network with VPN enabled.

Comment: @StuartBrock - sorry for not actively responding/trying your solution sooner to when you posted, but I've answered your question, and described my result with your answer, in the "Update" section to my post. Didn't work for me - but thank you: it looked promising, and looked like it _ought_ to have worked.

Comment: had the same issue, did a workaround guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68573952/11473934

Comment: Several workarounds for the problem are mentioned in [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5068), and one of them might work for you. The last and most elaborate was [AmmarRahman / wsl-vpn](https://github.com/AmmarRahman/wsl-vpn).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had similar issues with Cisco AnyConnect.  I think WSL1 does it's networking through Windows (via Hyper-V?) and WSL2 is effectively a Linux Kernel running virtualised alongside Windows.

My fix was

1. In Windows `ipconfig /all` get the DNS values for the VPN adaptor
2. In WSL `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf` and add the DNS values as lines `nameserver <DNS IP>`

You can optionally add the block below to `/etc/wsl.conf` to stop resolv.conf being "refreshed" (wiped) on restart.  But you need to remember it's not being automatically updated in future.

```
   [network]  
   generateResolvConf = false
```

As for why you had no network connection when VPN was connected, I think it was trying to connect to the "off VPN" DNS which your VPN was blocking.  There seem to be some GitHub issues around WSL2 and VPNs so I'd expect a fix to come out at some point.

Comment: Not just WSL2.. this happened with WSL (1) also.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas that wasn't the case for me with WSL1.  There is an issue with Cisco AnyConnect, if it's configured to, it'll remove access to your Local LAN and only allow VPN connections.  You should still be able to connect to servers on the VPN though if the DNS is configured correctly (or fixed in WSL2 as above).

Comment: It WAS the case for ***me*** with WSL1 ;)  We are all going to be resolv.conf gods before this is all over.

Comment: Seems that latest ubuntu20/wsl2 ignores `generateResolvConf = false` parameter and always re-create resolv.conf :(

Comment: This worked with Ubuntu-20.10 groovy and WSL-2. I did notice the /etc/resolv.conf does keep changing even after revising wsl.conf, but if you manually edit /etc/resolv.conf and change the nameserver lines to the ones that matchthe Ethernet adapter for the VPN from the WIndows shell output "ipconfig /all" then this works again.  Whew!  Hope a restart does not break the whole thing. Have not been able to run apt-get update for a couple of weeks.

Comment: Sorry for not returning to this much sooner. When I run `ipconfig /all`, I get the following three values: `fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1`, `fec0:0:0:ffff::1%2`, and `fec0:0:0:ffff::1%3`. What substring from one of those values is valid? I'm not sure what the `fec` and `%*` parts represent, but the middle looks like an IPv6 address. I tried the values verbatim, as well as stripped of the `fec` prefix and `%*` suffix, but those did not change the originally-described behavior. I have `generateResolvConf = false` in my `wsl.conf` and the behavior is unchanged even after restarting the Ubuntu app.

Comment: Three years after I posted my question, I found myself in a new environment, facing the same problem again! This time, your answer worked! So, very belated, I'm accepting this answer. :) I went through this, and every other posted answer, and all around the internet, but I never did find how to work around this problem in my prior environment, though. :(

Answer (score 13):

I used ubuntu_20 and WSL2 and I did the following steps to fix the issue:

- Run Powershell as administrator

  ```
  Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 4000  
  Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 1
  ```
- Find nameservers (command at windows powershell)

  ```
  ipconfig /all
  ```

  in my case I found values : `10.150.54.19` and `10.158.55.13`
- Make permanent changes to dns by edditing `/etc/wsl.conf` (inside WSL instance)

  ```
  [network]
  generateResolvConf = false
  ```
- shutdown WSL2 (command at PowerShell)

  ```
  wsl --shutdown
  ```

  afterwards open new terminal window with wsl
- delete and create new `/etc/resolv.conf` file

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
  sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- add the following at the `resolv.conf`

  ```
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 10.150.54.19
  nameserver 10.158.55.13
  ```
- the first step *(two powershell commands)* need to be executed  every time we are connected to the vpn

Comment: The first two PowerShell (run as admin) commands both returned no output.
`ipconfig /all` returned some IPV6 addresses. I documented my experience -- which was still unsuccessful -- trying to use those values in the update to my post.

Comment: Hi! This solution works, however the host and the WSL can't access the websites that require the VPN.

Comment: @GeorgianStan I think that this is not true. I can access the sites inside the VPN. Maybe you also have to set a proxy in your case

Answer (score 8):

There's an [easy workaround](https://superuser.com/a/1683898/1129381) that worked for me on Windows 10 with WSL2+Ubuntu 20.04 and Cisco AnyConnect.:

Launch WSL before connecting to the VPN:

```
wsl --shutdown
# disconnect VPN
wsl
# connect VPN again
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it solved my issue. But it would be nice not to need to do this :-)

Comment: Might be worth noting this is doing the WSL equivalent of rebooting your machine! Make sure anything open is saved. Otherwise, good thing to try.

Comment: Returning to this thread after a long time (gave up in despair), and unfortunately, this did not work for me. I followed the posted sequence, then in my Ubuntu instance (which I started before re-connecting VPN), I ran `ping www.google.com` and again got the same `Temporary failure in name resolution` error.

Answer (score 7):

I did the following to provide network connectivity to the WSL 2 VM while connected to VPNs on the Windows host.

**1.** Download the distro [wsl-vpnkit.tar.gz](https://github.com/sakai135/wsl-vpnkit/releases) and copy it to *C:\Users\<username>*

**2.** Open a PowerShell in *C:\Users\<username>* and run these commands

> wsl.exe --import wsl-vpnkit $env:USERPROFILE\wsl-vpnkit
> wsl-vpnkit.tar.gz
>
> wsl.exe -d wsl-vpnkit
>
> wsl.exe -d wsl-vpnkit service wsl-vpnkit start

**3.** To prevent having to re-run any commands, open a WSL 2 session window and run

> sudo nano ~/.bashrc

Append this command below and save

> wsl.exe -d wsl-vpnkit service wsl-vpnkit start >/dev/null 2>&1

**.bashrc** runs on every interactive shell launch.

**4.** Close and re-open a new WSL 2 session.
To confirm network access, run a ping command

> ping google.com

Comment: This saved my day. What's the magic behind wsl-vpnkit?

Comment: For kafka running inside docker from wsl2, it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Mcafee, see this article - https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB94601

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'm leaving it as a link because this is a temporary mcafee solution, if the link no longer works, then the issue should no longer be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had setup WSL2(Ubuntu) in Windows10. When connecting to GlobalProtect VPN I was able to get internet both in Windows10 and WSL2 but certain VPN sites were not accessible (company kubernetes api server hosted thru AWS load balancer).
On internet I found this page https://janovesk.com/wsl/2022/01/21/wsl2-and-vpn-routing.html and got my solution by adding routes for sites that were not reachable over VPN from WSL2.
I created a powershell script to be executed every time I connect to VPN. This can be automated by creating event triggered task as mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5068#issuecomment-1263904885

If one wants then one can execute this powershell from inside WSL2(Ubuntu) bash also `powershell.exe Start-Process -Verb runas -FilePath powershell.exe "C:\Users\Sushil.Sah\Desktop\route_edit.ps1"`

My powershell script:

```
#this script needs to be run as administrator to be able to add routes

$adapter = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "PANGP"}
Write-Output "VPN interface index = $($adapter.ifIndex) "

$adapter_ip = Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $adapter.ifIndex
Write-Output "VPN IP = $($adapter_ip.IPAddress) "

function add_routes_after_resolving
{
  param(
    [string]$website_name = $(Throw 'website name is required')
  )

  $IPs = Resolve-DnsName $website_name
  Write-Output "DNS Resolved IPs for $($website_name) are below "

  ForEach($IP in $IPs.IPAddress)
  {
    Write-Output "$($IP)"
    route ADD $IP MASK 255.255.255.255 $adapter_ip.IPAddress METRIC 1 IF $adapter.ifIndex
  }
}

Write-Output "Routes before adding"
route print

add_routes_after_resolving google.com #replace with whatever website_name we want to add route for

#if following routes are not added by VPN client then to add it manually
#one can change IP and subnet mask according to their company IPs that needs to be connected over VPN
route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 $adapter_ip.IPAddress METRIC 1 IF $adapter.ifIndex
route ADD 172.16.0.0 MASK 255.240.0.0 $adapter_ip.IPAddress METRIC 1 IF $adapter.ifIndex
route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 $adapter_ip.IPAddress METRIC 1 IF $adapter.ifIndex

Write-Output "Routes after adding"
route print
```

Answer (score -1):

An easier and faster solution is to **turn off windows firewall**. I know its an extremely bad idea but at this point, this is the solution that works for me.